# vba code to download multiple files from website

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering that I can get some help with this code,

I am trying to download files from a website, the code I am using is

```
Public Sub DownloadFile()
Dim weblink As String
weblink = "https://documentflowmanagerus.abcabc.com/DFM_HBTC/Default.aspx?page=RetrDocView.aspx&URN="
Set Rng = Range("A1:A100")

For Each cell In Rng
        'test if cell is empty
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
        link = weblink & cell.Value
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=link, NewWindow:=False
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

this code is working alright, on the column A there is a list of all URN numbers where it loops,

this code loops through column A and goes to hyperlink to download file

the trouble is I have to save all the files manually , since each time it loops it opens a new tab in the browser

I am looking for a way that it closes the tab automatically and download file without manually saving it

Comment: Is the hyperlink the direct location of the file ? I believe you can use the a different library and save the file rather then followhyperlink

Comment: yes the hyperlink is the direct location for the file. to access the files I have to Log in to the website that's why I did it this way, because once I am logged in it is not asking for the username and password again